# In Hybrid Setup will Basic Authentication still work to On-Prem Exchange

Tags: office365, exchange-server, microsoft-graph-api

Will an on-prem Exchange Server (operating in a Hybrid Setup) continue to support BASIC AUTHENTICATION via IMAP and EWS?

We know that Microsoft is disabling BASIC AUTHENTICATION for Exchange Online. We have an application that still uses BASIC AUTHENTICATION over IMAP/EWS to retrieve emails by connecting to the on-prem Exchange Server (not the Exchange Online endpoints).

We were wondering if it will stop working when Microsoft disables BASIC AUTHENTICATION on the online part of the Hybrid setup.

Note: The plan is to upgrade the software to use MSGraph and Microsoft Modern Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have security defaults enabled, basic auth will be blocked but if you are using conditional access policies you can exempt any/all users from blocking legacy auth. I've seen this used in a lot of cases where legacy on-prem apps still need to connect via EWS/SMTP/IMAP.

When/If Microsoft decides to completely disable basic auth, a LOT of on-prem apps will stop functioning.

Comment: Thanks for responding.   Microsoft is planning on disabling BASIC AUTH on all Office365 tenants in Oct 2022.  They said this change WILL NOT affect on-prem Exchange servers...ONLY Office 365.

If we were using Office 365 Only, we would be forced to update our application to use Microsoft Modern Authentication.

If we were On-prem Only, we could continue to use Basic Authentication past the Oct 2022 deadline.

Wondering how a Hybrid configuration will be affected.  Can we continue to use BASIC AUTH to connect to our On-prem servers in a Hybrid configuration after Oct 2022?

Comment: I posted a similar question to Microsoft Q&A. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/795456/can-basic-auth-still-be-used-to-authenticate-to-on.html

The answer from AndyDavid was:   Yes, absolutely. The change in ExO will not affect basic auth to on-prem Exchange. The apps will continue to connect to Exch on-prem and then the messages can be routed as they are now to Exchange Online.